# Adding event handler and expression trees

Tags: .net, events, c#-4.0, expression-trees

How to make lambda like this

```
Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>> adder = vs => GenericEvent += vs
```

using expression trees. This code doesn't work:

```
Expression<Func<EventHandler<TEventArgs>>> handler = () => GenericEvent;
var vs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(EventHandler<TEventArgs>), "vs");    
var adder = Expression.Lambda<Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>>>(
            Expression.AddAssign(handler.Body, vs), vs).Compile();
```

Error message:

> The binary operator AddAssign is not defined for the types 'System.EventHandler`1[ConsoleApplication.Program+SomeEventArgs]' and 'System.EventHandler`1[ConsoleApplication.Program+SomeEventArgs]'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to start with you need to be very clear in your mind the difference between events and delegate fields.

We can't tell what `GenericEvent` is in the first case, but if it really *does* refer to an event, that will be calling `add_GenericEvent` or whatever the appropriate underlying metadata gives. Compare that with the second case, where you really want to call `Delegate.Combine`, cast the result back to `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` and then assign it back to `GenericEvent`. In both cases the C# compiler is using syntactic sugar really - and you need to unpick that sugar to create the relevant expression tree.

Comment: @l33t: Without more clarity in the question, it's hard to write the appropriate code. If you're in a similar position but can't get it to work, ask a new question with a [mcve].